# Is the idiom 'keeping well' recognized only in British English?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english

I've seen the idiom 'keeping well' being used to mean 'in good health' in some contexts where British English is expected. But Americans seem surprised by it. Is that idiom uncommon in American English?

Comment: Ams today say *I'm good* to the utter dismay of the Brits.

Comment: I just looked at several idiom sources, and all the uses sound very strange to me. AmE here.

Comment: *keep well* by itself as kind of a parting statement or the like would be comprehensible to me, but any other use of it would be strange to me. (AmE here).

Comment: I would say [staying well](http://books.google.com/books?id=Op5mZyWTMvYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22staying+well%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=83RGU6u4DoPt2QX6vID4Cw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22staying%20well%22&f=false), and I think many other Americans would do the same.

Comment: It appears Americans are more likely to use stay than keep in phrases like this. [See Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+out+of+trouble%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cstay+out+of+trouble%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cstay+out+of+trouble%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ckeep+out+of+trouble%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20out%20of%20trouble%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20out%20of%20trouble%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20out%20of%20trouble%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20out%20of%20trouble%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*only cont.*: Reverso (see below) records it as of 'exclusively continental usage'.

*De tuenda sanitate* by Plutarch: "[Advice about Keeping Well](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Moralia/De_tuenda_sanitate%2a.html)"

> Plutarch had more than a casual interest in medicine, for, besides this essay on keeping well, his other works abound in references to the behaviour of the sick and their treatment, and the medical practices of his day.

*[keeping well](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/keeping%20well)*:

> You can say or ask how someone is keeping as a way of saying or asking whether they are well.
>   ***only cont***
>   *She hasn't been keeping too well lately...*

The ***only cont*** seems to refer to the usage in the continent alone, so it's alien to NAmer. usage.